# Error 43 The type or namespace name 'ViewAsPdf' does not exist in the namespace 'Rotativa' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am getting this error:

> Error 40  The type or namespace name 'ViewAsPdf' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Rotativa' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)   D:\SandeepPatil\PPD_Projects\Code\Karma_Retail\Karma.Store\Areas\Admin\Controllers\OrderController.cs   1757    45  Karma.Retail.Web

[image]

Comment: *Should* that type exist?  Why do you think it would?

Comment: In error sir Asp net Mvc how to solve .

Comment: You have two options to "solve" the "error":  (1) Include the libraries you're trying to use.  or (2) Don't try to use types that don't exist.

Comment: Please write your code in the post instead of putting a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

You may be missing the reference to the Rotativa dll which was reported as an error in version 1.7.3, found [here](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa/issues/177). There's now a prerelease version 1.7.4-rc which presumably fixes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

[This error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Gibs.png) is caused by trying to instantiate a `Rotativa.ViewAsPdf` object which, I am pretty sure, is not an object but a static method of the class Rotativa.

From the surrounding code I can read on your screenshot, I can assume the method `ViewAsPdf` returns a byte array, in which case the simplest solution would be to remove the `new` in front of it, which serves absolutely nothing in that case.

Please note that this answer is only based on assumptions due to the low amount of informations provided by your screenshot. You might want to publish your code in the question for us to better understand the context.